# Adjusting the visual state of a button when ContextMenu is open or closed in WPF app

Tags: wpf, storyboard, eventtrigger

In a WPF app I'm working on, there is a `Button` `Style` which defines it's own `Template` (`ControlTemplate`).

I handles visual updates via `ControlTemplate.Triggers`, like the following for `IsMouseOver`:

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
  <Trigger.EnterActions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation 
              Storyboard.TargetName="IsMouseOverBorder" 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
              To="1" 
              Duration="0:0:0.08" />
          </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
  </Trigger.EnterActions>
  <Trigger.ExitActions>
      <BeginStoryboard>
          <Storyboard>
            <DoubleAnimation 
              Storyboard.TargetName="IsMouseOverBorder" 
              Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
              To="0" 
              Duration="0:0:0.16" />
          </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
  </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

I've added a context menu to some `Button`s which use this style. Having done so, when right-clicking on a `Button`, the context menu shows, but the `IsMouseOver` trigger then immediately does it's Exit action. I would prefer that the `IsMouseOver` visual state is maintained while the context menu is open – it would look much nicer.

How can I do this?

Here's a couple of additional triggers which I thought would achieve what I want, but it doesn't. The first trigger (`ContextMenuOpening`) works, but the second trigger does not - the button is left in a permanent `IsMouseOver` looking state.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContextMenuService.ContextMenuOpening">
  <BeginStoryboard Name="ContextMenuOpeningStoryboard">
    <Storyboard>
      <DoubleAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetName="IsMouseOverBorder" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" 
        To="1" 
        Duration="0" />
    </Storyboard>
  </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>

<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ContextMenuService.ContextMenuClosing">
  <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="ContextMenuOpeningStoryboard" />
</EventTrigger>
```

Any idea why this won't work, or an alternate method that would work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work using the styles as defined in my question, but I had to manually raise the `ContextMenuService.ContextMenuClosingEvent` event (using some reflection to do so):

```
<ContextMenu Closed="ContextMenu_Closed">...</ContextMenu>
```

Code behind:

```
private void ContextMenu_Closed(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{

  var type = typeof(ContextMenuEventArgs);

  var contextMenuEventArgs = (ContextMenuEventArgs) type.Assembly.CreateInstance
  (
    type.FullName, false, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, 
    new object[] { this, false }, null, null
  );

  if (contextMenuEventArgs != null) 
  {
    contextMenuEventArgs.RoutedEvent = ContextMenuService.ContextMenuClosingEvent;
    _myToggleButton.RaiseEvent(contextMenuEventArgs);
  }

}
```